# php script won't connect MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

This is the code. and for some reason I can't find out why it is not working.
As you can see I've added a test query to see if it affects any changes on my db but nope :(

The funny thing is that in another php script I have succeeded to connect the db and even added some records to it thru the php script. Can't find the problem, Thanks from advance.
BTW. as you can see I have already defined the var "month" as string "hey" and echo it in the end of the php script to see if it changes. but nothing is happen!!

> ```
>   <form action="" name="form" id="form">
>       <label>
>           Select the month which you want to display its days.
>           <select name="month" form="form" required>
>             <option value="january">January</option>
>             <option value="february">February</option>
>             <option value="march">March</option>
>             <option value="april">April</option>
>             <option value="may">May</option>
>             <option value="june">June</option>
>             <option value="july">July</option>
>             <option value="august">August</option>
>             <option value="september">September</option>
>             <option value="october">October</option>
>             <option value="november">November</option>
>             <option value="december">December</option>
>           </select>
>       </label>
>       <input type="submit" name="update" value="Display" />
>   </form>
>   <?php
>   $month = "hey";
>   if(isset($_POST["update"]))
>   {
>       $month = $_POST["month"];
>       $query = "SELECT * FROM `days` WHERE `month`='{$month}';";
>       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db123");
>       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
>       mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `days`(`month`,`day`) VALUES ('test','10');");
>       if($result)
>       {
>           die("Sorry!");
>       }
>       while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
>       {
>           echo $month;
>           print_r($row);
>       }
>       mysqli_close($conn);
>       echo $month;
>   }
>
>      ?
> ```

Comment: Check whether db is connected or not? Using this `if($conn){echo "Connected";}else{"Not Connected"}`

Comment: What is the output of print_r($conn);

Comment: Where is `>` in the last line. Can you give us the full code? There is no `<html>` in your code

Comment: Also instead of if($result) it should be if(!$result) FYI

Comment: @user4412293 Please select an answer to close off this topic

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified the method , its GET by default if.Change this line

```
 if(isset($_POST["update"]))
```

to this

```
 if(isset($_GET["update"]))
```

. Or if you want to use method as POST than just specify the method as POST
 use the code below

```
 <form action="" name="form" id="form" method="POST">
      <label>
          Select the month which you want to display its days.
          <select name="month" form="form" required>
            <option value="january">January</option>
            <option value="february">February</option>
            <option value="march">March</option>
            <option value="april">April</option>
            <option value="may">May</option>
            <option value="june">June</option>
            <option value="july">July</option>
            <option value="august">August</option>
            <option value="september">September</option>
            <option value="october">October</option>
            <option value="november">November</option>
            <option value="december">December</option>
          </select>
      </label>
      <input type="submit" name="update" value="Display" />
  </form>
  <?php
  $month = "hey";
  if(isset($_POST["update"]))
  {
      $month = $_POST["month"];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `days` WHERE `month`='{$month}';";
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db123");
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
      mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `days`(`month`,`day`) VALUES ('test','10');");
      if($result)
      {
          die("Sorry!");
      }
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
      {
          echo $month;
          print_r($row);
      }
      mysqli_close($conn);
      echo $month;
  }

     ?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db123");
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  }
 $month = "hey";
 if(isset($_POST["update"]))
  {
  $month = $_POST["month"];
  $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `days` WHERE `month`='{$month}'");
  mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `days`(`month`,`day`) VALUES ('test','10');");
  while($row = $res->num_rows)
  {
      echo $month;
      print_r($row);
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);
  echo $month;
 }
?>
```